# creating a cloud server for fun

Tags: cloud, virtualhost, web-hosting, google-cloud-storage

Ive tried researching but too much information is not very clear. Most searches relate to an actual business opening of hosting cloud storage, which is not what I want to do. I want to do one for fun, and something to add to my resume as a project.

So, I was wondering what are the steps to create a cloud storage?

this is what I gasped in my searches, but I am not sure if this is right and what else is missing.

1.) A server computer that always stays on
2.) A website so I can "register" for fun and practice
3.) A server computer with at least 2TB of memory (for educational purpose and self use and friends)
4.) A bit of programming to set up the site

now the problem I have in finding when I search is, how exactly does the server computer host off its memory to a website? how does it make that connection?

kind of like drop box.

I want it to go online, store it in my server computer, then go to my website from any PC and save it or view it on any computer that leads to my server PC

Any information would be great!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a personal VPS solution. Search VPS, FAPVPS is good IMHO for this purpose, then install apache and then install a file server that would serve the files on the server.